# Why is there no variation in output of cochrans Q test from statsmodel library in this code?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I am using following code:

```
from statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables import cochrans_q 
res = cochrans_q([[1,4,5],[9,6,8]])
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
df          2
pvalue      0.36787944117144245
statistic   2.0
```

However, output remains same for `[[10,4,5],[9,6,8]]`, `[[55,88,77],[99,46,88]]` etc.

The statsmodels documentation page is [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.cochrans_q.html) and the Wikipedia page on Cochran's Q test is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_Q_test).

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: based on the unit tests, cochrans_q takes the original binary data and not counts https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/stats/tests/test_nonparametric.py#L142

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. And answer also changes with change in array. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I struggle to see what that 3 by 2 array represents in any case. If you observe a dichotomous response across, say, 3 treatments with 33 blocks, you get a 2-by-2-by-2 contingency table (with the grand total of its counts coming to 33).

Comment: I had fed them as 2 rows of a contingency table that could reflect anything: for example, comparison of 2 drugs, the side-effects of which are measured as ordinal variable, say `[mild, moderate, severe]`. I believe Cochran's Q test is not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cochrans_q takes binary data and not counts.

In statsmodels the documentation is often not very explicit, but the expected behavior can be seen from the unit tests.

The following unit test shows how to convert frequency data to the format required by statsmodels.

source: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/stats/tests/test_nonparametric.py#L190

```
def test_cochransq3():
    # another example compared to SAS
    # in frequency weight format
    dt = [('A', 'S1'), ('B', 'S1'), ('C', 'S1'), ('count', int)]
    dta = np.array([('F', 'F', 'F', 6),
                    ('U', 'F', 'F', 2),
                    ('F', 'F', 'U', 16),
                    ('U', 'F', 'U', 4),
                    ('F', 'U', 'F', 2),
                    ('U', 'U', 'F', 6),
                    ('F', 'U', 'U', 4),
                    ('U', 'U', 'U', 6)], dt)

    cases = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                      [1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1],
                      [1, 0, 1],
                      [0, 1, 0],
                      [1, 1, 0],
                      [0, 1, 1],
                      [1, 1, 1]])
    count = np.array([ 6,  2, 16,  4,  2,  6,  4,  6])
    data = np.repeat(cases, count, 0)

    res = cochrans_q(data)
    assert_allclose([res.statistic, res.pvalue], [8.4706, 0.0145], atol=5e-5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the definitions of each result:

---

> [**df:**](https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/degrees-freedom-statistics/) In statistics, the degrees of freedom (DF) indicate the number of independent values that can
> vary in an analysis without breaking any constraints. It is an essential idea that appears in
> many contexts throughout statistics including hypothesis tests,
> probability distributions, and regression analysis.

---

> [**pvalue:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) In statistics, the p-value is the probability of obtaining results as extreme as the observed
> results of a statistical hypothesis test, assuming that the null hypothesis is correct.

---

> [**statistic:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic) A statistic (singular) or sample statistic is any quantity computed from values in a sample
> that is used for a statistical purpose. Statistical purposes include estimating a population parameter,
> describing a sample, or evaluating a hypothesis.

---

As you can see, the definitions have nothing to do with values of each element, it's the quantity that counts.

Your program retursn the same thing for

`[[1,4,5],[9,6,8]]`, `[[10,4,5],[9,6,8]]`, `[[55,88,77],[99,46,88]]`, etc 
because each list has 3 elements in them.

Cochran's Q Test is a **non parametric** way to find differences in matched sets of three or more frequencies or proportions. That means that when performing the Cochran's Q test, **the values of each element don't matter**.

Comment: @rnso because the values of df, p and statistic don't rely in the value of the elements, they rely on the *amount* of elements.

Comment: If it is only counting number of values, how do I perform Cochran's test on different values?

Comment: @rnso You can do what you just did, and the test results will be the same.

Comment: How can I do Cochran's Q test with above code, using data on this page: https://www.statisticshowto.com/cochrans-q-test/

Comment: Where is your definition from? See definition at Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_Q_test

Comment: @rnso from the page you linked: *Cochran's Q test is a non-parametric statistical test*. non-parametric means the values of each element don't influence the results.

Comment: I regularly use statistics, and I think you are not correct about "non-parametric tests". https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/56211/rnso?tab=profile

Comment: Nonparametric statistics is the branch of statistics that is not based solely on parametrized families of probability distributions (common examples of parameters are the mean and variance). (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics))

Comment: On this page https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/cochrans-q-test-in-spss-statistics.php there is 3x2 frequencies table- that has different result of Cochran's Q test.

Comment: @rnso Can you give a screenshot?

Comment: Search for "Frequencies Table" on that page.  Result is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @rnso The df is the same, and they didn't show pvalue and statistic.

Comment: At bottom of page: p < .0005. Also see link posted by @Josef in comment below the question.